# Jquery: append more complex html fragment

Tags: jquery, append, fragment

I would like to append a more complex html fragment to a div using jquery. I am able to achieve this, **but how can I do this in a single append call** (right now I have several)?. Any comments appreciated! Thanks a lot. Example:

```
<div id="container">
   <h1>Something</h1>
   <!-- Insert here -->
</div>
```

the fragment should look like this:

```
var arr = []; // can contain any number of items
//to be used here:
<h4>Something h4</h4><!-- This string is static -->
<p>Some paragraf</p><!-- This string is static -->
<ul> <!-- This is dynamic -->
   <li>arr[0]</li>
   <li>arr[1]</li>
   <li>arr[2]</li>
   <li>arr[...]</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `I am able to achieve this, but I would like to know what is the best/most elegant (performance-wise) way to do this`. Indicates this should be over at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://odereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Edit, so maybe now I can get some CONSTRUCTIVE answer. Thanks.

Comment: This still is difficult to assess. How are you populating the array list? what's in the array? what are the circumstances under which the dynamic list should be processed? Are you looking to template it instead? is it possible to use JSON and inject into the structure?

Comment: The array is not really important. We can assume there will be simply 0-100 items in it. It is always populated on the fly by user actions, it is basically an error list. I am just looking for the best way to append this (if possible with query append call).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(arr, function(i,a){
    $('ul').append('<li>'+a+'</li>'); 
});
```

Based on your above comments. Iterate the list, extrapolate the value as `a` and append to the value to a newly created list element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one call to `append()` and a `map()`, but not sure if it's more efficient than just a simple loop, but it does look cooler :

```
var arr = ['error 1', 'error 2', 'error 3', 'error 4', 'error 5'];

$('<ul />', {id:'someID'}).append(function() {
    return $.map(arr, function(error) { return $('<li>', {text:error}) });
}).appendTo('#container');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N45V4/)

Comment: Is it possible to append it to the ul tag and at the same time creating the ul dynamically (right now you have it hardcoded)? How would I do that with a single append call? The only way I could figure it out was to make a string and just joining it with +=.